# outlook web-addin not working on desktop client

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've developed a web-addin for outlook365. However, for some reason, the add-in stops working on desktop client. It just load the HTML page for the taskpane but not executing the taskpane.js. The add-in still works on web based outlook. I tried to investigate the issue, found that the Office.onReady handler is not called on desktop client. Any idea what could be the cause?

Thanks,
Peng

Answer (score 0):

The `Office.initialize = function () {};` needs to be called first.

If an Outlook add-in running on Windows is not working correctly, try turning on script debugging in Internet Explorer.

- Go to `Tools` > `Internet Options` > `Advanced`.
- Under `Browsing`, uncheck `Disable script debugging` (Internet Explorer) .

We recommend that you uncheck these settings only to troubleshoot the issue. If you leave them unchecked, you will get prompts when you browse. After the issue is resolved, check `Disable script debugging` (Internet Explorer) again.

Comment: Additionally remember the IE is currently being used as the engine to power apps on Desktop Client. If you are using advanced JS features not supported (such as Arrow Functions) then it is likely you are getting an exception. A more modern experience (using edge) is rolling out on machines/office versions that support it: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Finally, I use `Office.onReady();` rather than `Office.initialize = function () {};`. Refer to the link below for more details :

[Outlook addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office)